# Trying to create a test to test my square_root method in python 2.7.5

Tags: python, unit-testing, calculator

New to programming so apologies if this is a basic question.
I am creating a functioning calculator and need to be able to test it to ensure it works as it should. So far everything has run ok, but when I tried to test my square_root method I am encountering the following error:

AssertionError: ValueError not raised

### Here is my code:

```
import unittest

class Calculator(object):

    def square_root(self, x):
        from math import sqrt
        number_types = (int, float, complex, long)

        try:
            if isinstance(x, number_types):
                return sqrt(x)
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except:
            return "nan"

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculator()

    def test_to_see_square_root_works_ok(self):
        result = self.calc.square_root(4)
        self.assertEqual(2, result)
        result = self.calc.square_root(0)
        self.assertEqual(0, result)
        result = self.calc.square_root(-4)
        self.assertEqual("nan", result)
    def test_calculator_returns_error_message_if_x_arg_is_not_number(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.calc.square_root, 'two')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

I have no idea why it is not raising a value error as I have specified the number types above. I have several other calculator functions that have all passed without error but I cannot figure this one out. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you have two possible input errors that are distinct but handled as the same exception, `ValueError`. If you run `sqrt(-4)`, you will get a `ValueError` exception. Either way, the exception will be raised for the input `'two'` because it is not a numeric type. Then the `except` clause is invoked which will return `'nan'`, overriding the return of the exception because Python thinks you've handled the exception. What you really have are two distinct errors: a math error where the input is outside the domain of the square root operation and a data type error where the input is not a numeric type. I would handle it using the following code which uses a custom exception and two `except` clauses to differentiate between the two cases:

```
import unittest

class DataError(Exception):
    pass

class Calculator(object):

    def square_root(self, x):
            from math import sqrt
            number_types = (int, float, complex, long)
            try:
                    if isinstance(x, number_types):
                            return sqrt(x)
                    else:
                            raise DataError("Not a numeric type")
            except ValueError:
                    return "nan"
            except DataError:
                    raise

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
            self.calc = Calculator()

    def test_to_see_square_root_works_ok(self):
            self.assertEqual(2, self.calc.square_root(4))
            self.assertEqual(0, self.calc.square_root(0))
            self.assertEqual("nan", self.calc.square_root(-4))

    def test_calculator_returns_error_message_if_x_arg_is_not_number(self):
            self.assertRaises(DataError, self.calc.square_root, [self, 'two$

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Or, in lieu of that, just assume that your user knows not to take the square root of a negative number and handle only the `ValueError` since 'two' is not a number.